# Bootstrap modal window weird display

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am testing the Boostrap 3 modal with ajax remote server dynamic loading
before loading the modal window is correct ( white background) but once the ajax request is performed and dat are loaded into modal-content, the modal-header (title) and modal-footer ( buttons) are displayed with transparent background

my modal is the standard Bootstrap example :

```
        #myModal.modal.fade{ tabindex: "-1" ,role: "dialog", :'aria-labelledby' => "myModalLabel",  :'aria-hidden' => "true"}
        .modal-dialog
            .modal-header
                %button.close{type: "button",  :'data-dismiss' => "modal" }
                    %span{:'aria-hidden' => true}
                        &times;
                    %span.sr-only
                        = t(:close, scope: :application).capitalize
                %h4#myModalLabel.modal-title
                    = t(:select_album_owner, scope: :album).capitalize
            .modal-content
                = "Loading..."
            .modal-footer
                %button.btn.btn-default{type: "button",  :'data-dismiss' => "modal" }
                    = t(:close, scope: :application).capitalize
                %button.btn.btn-primary{type: "button",  :'data-dismiss' => "modal" }
                    = t(:select, scope: :application).capitalize
```

the ajax url request is performed upon click on the following link

```
<a class="btn btn-success static-popup-link" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="http://localhost:3000/backoffice/users.js?locale=fr" remote="true" type="text"><span>rechercher</span></a>
```

the users_controller index action  :

```
    class Backoffice::UsersController < ApplicationController

      respond_to :html, :js

      def index
        sort_order = "updated_at DESC , username"
        @users = User.order(sort_order).page params[:page]
        respond_with(@user)
      end
```

and the  view back office/users/index.js.erb  is very simple... for testing

```
   <%=  @users.count %>
```

this works, the users count is displayed inside the modal pane ( in modal-content , replacing the "loading..." text  BUT header and footer are transparent ...

why ? and how to get the white background in all the modal panel including head and footer ?

thanks for suggestions ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup seems to be wrong. `modal-content` is supposed to *contain* `modal-header`, `modal-body`, and `modal-footer`, **not** be their *sibling*. Read [the docs examples](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) more closely. Also, consider using something like [Bh](https://github.com/Fullscreen/bh).

Comment: thanks ... I looked over bh, interesting however using Ajax requests to insert content from remote server, I found this link , working fin w Rails 4, Bootstrap 3, simple_form 3.1.0.rc2  :  https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/wiki/Ruby-on-Rails----AJAX-Modal-Example !!